# Can't evaluate Conditional Formatting of COUNTIF function

Tags: vba, excel, conditional-formatting

I'm having problems checking if my conditional formatting equates to true in VBA. Formatting works correctly on the spreadsheet and changes the cell colours but VBA is showing no conditioning is applied when the COUNTIF function is used.

On each cell within a range I have set up three conditions:

```
1: =WEEKDAY(DATE($B$4,$A$5,$C$4),2)>5 - Changes colour if the day is a weekend (light blue)
2: =COUNTIF($AL:$AL,DATE($B$4,$A$5,$C$4))>0 - Checks a range (AL column) to see if the date appears in it (dark blue)
3: =COUNTIF($AM:$AM,DATE($B$4,$A$5,$C$4))>0 - Same as above but checks a different column (yellow)
```

Its a holiday spreadsheet. Column AL holds any public holidays that are set and column AM holds holidays that the company sets. The calendar then highlights the grid with weekends and holidays

B4 - Year
A5 - Month
C4 - Date

A5 & C4 addresses change depending what cell is selected however I have had to use absolute addresses as evaluate doesn't work with relative addresses.

In my VBA code I need to check if a condition has been applied and put a value of "P" for public hols or "Z" for company hols. When running the VBA however it does not recognise that these conditions have been met.

Condition 1 is picked up on as TRUE but it does not see when the other 2 conditions have been met even though the colours have changed on the sheet?

I tried taking out the DATE within the COUNTIF and hardcoding a string but still didn't pick it up in VBA so it's not that.

To return the active condition in VBA I am using:

```
For Ndx = 1 To Rng.FormatConditions.Count
    Set FC = Rng.FormatConditions(Ndx)

        If Application.Evaluate(FC.Formula1) Then
           ActiveCondition = Ndx
           Exit Function
        End If

Next Ndx
```

Comment: So you have a different formula for every cell? And you could evaluate every formula regardless of its position? What if you copy the conditions to a cell (not the formatconsition; just as a cell-formula)? Are they evaluated as expected? And if you pick up the cell-value with your code (instead of the format-condition-value) is everything as expected? If so: can you just edit your question to show some conditions for other cells?

Comment: @Johanness I gave up doing it this way. Took too long to get a reply so instead of using conditional formatting I have coded some VBA to loop round the grid, constructing a date string based on what cell it loops to next and then compare this compiled date to the dates stored of the holiday sheet. If it finds a match it formats the cell colour and changes the value to P or Z

Comment: To answer your question though, if i put the condition in another cell as a function the value changed to TRUE however the evaluate in VBA still wasnt picking it up. It wasnt so much a different formula in each cell it was just cell names that changed so for instance the conditions above were taken from cell C5, conditions in C6 would be =COUNTIF($AL:$AL,DATE($B$4,$A$6,$C$4))>0 In cell B4 is my year, columns C4:AG4 hold the days of the month, A5:A16 hold the months. So a calendar grid

Comment: Thnaks for the clarification. As you seem to be going another route I dont think it necessary to pursue this. Happy coding